# When using data binding, how do I know when a control was added?

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding

When using data binding, how do I know when a control was added?

I'm using ItemsControl element with ItemTemplate.

I want to know when a control was added like event(ex. OnControlAdded)

Please help me

Comment: There is no `OnControlAdded` event. If you could give us more context, on what you're trying to do, it would help us give you a specific response.

Comment: @abhinav OnControlAdded is a just example, not existing. I just want to receive the notification from ItemsControl when a new contorol is added

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it's supposed to work, you got it upside down.

You're supposed to have a ViewModel, and Collection in there that you then bind to your ItemsControl.
On that collection, which should be observable, you have a `CollectionChanged` event. Subscribe to this one, it will fire when elements are added/removed which in turn will make your ItemsControl grow/shrink.

Comment: My purpose is... when user input 'enter' in textbox, i add a new item in observablecollection which is bound with ItemsControl. so ItemsControl makes a new textbox. but i want for the new textbox to get focus! so i left this question 'how do i know when -'

Comment: I solved this problem using control's Loaded event. but i can't be certain about my solution.